# Two time-dependent data sets, which test do I use?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a data set for crab heart rate, in two groups, one at a higher temperature and one at a lower temperature. Both data sets are time-dependent (measuring heart rate after stress in hot and cold crabs). Because both sets are dependent on time I can't use a t-test, and I'm really at a loss.

If I compare the means I get a really strong correlation, but as you can see from the graph the standard errors are MASSIVE.

[image: graph]